# Issue with ASUS Touch Screen Monitor and Android Device

Tags: android, driver, native, touchscreen, android-kernel

I am connecting my Android Device with ASUS VT168H monitor over USB and HDMI. The issue I am having is with the asus touch screen monitor. It doesn't invoke the proper touch, means if I touch at at the bottom of the screen the actual touch will happen at the top of the screen.

Now, when I connect some other touch monitor, e.g. DELL S2240T, every thing is working correctly both display and touch.

Though debugging what I found was, on the ASUS monitor android device was invoking the ELAN Touch Screen driver. See below log:

`12-10 10:59:09.402  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/mouse1' due to inotify event
12-10 10:59:09.403  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device ELAN Touchscreen due to epoll hang-up event.
12-10 10:59:09.403  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removed device: path=/dev/input/event7 name=ELAN Touchscreen id=17 fd=265 classes=0x80000014
12-10 10:59:09.407  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/event7' due to inotify event
12-10 10:59:11.895  1743  1982 E EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
12-10 10:59:11.908  1743  1982 D EventHub: No input device configuration file found for device 'ELAN Touchscreen'.
12-10 10:59:11.908  1743  1982 I EventHub: wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
12-10 10:59:11.908  1743  1982 I EventHub: New device: id=18, fd=189, path='/dev/input/event7', name='ELAN Touchscreen', classes=0x80000014, configuration='', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false, 
12-10 11:12:26.994  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device ELAN Touchscreen due to epoll hang-up event.
12-10 11:12:26.994  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removed device: path=/dev/input/event7 name=ELAN Touchscreen id=18 fd=189 classes=0x80000014
12-10 11:12:27.004  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/mouse1' due to inotify event
12-10 11:12:27.004  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/event7' due to inotify event
12-10 11:14:56.491  1743  1982 E EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
12-10 11:14:56.504  1743  1982 D EventHub: No input device configuration file found for device 'ELAN Touchscreen'.
12-10 11:14:56.504  1743  1982 I EventHub: wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
12-10 11:14:56.504  1743  1982 I EventHub: New device: id=19, fd=267, path='/dev/input/event7', name='ELAN Touchscreen', classes=0x80000014, configuration='', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false,`

while on the Dell Monitor, it was invoking the "Weida Hi-Tech CoolTouch System" driver. See below log:

`12-10 11:39:23.182  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/mouse1' due to inotify event
12-10 11:39:23.183  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device ELAN Touchscreen due to epoll hang-up event.
12-10 11:39:23.183  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removed device: path=/dev/input/event7 name=ELAN Touchscreen id=20 fd=277 classes=0x80000014
12-10 11:39:23.185  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/event7' due to inotify event
12-10 11:51:57.548  1743  1982 E EventHub: could not get driver version for /dev/input/mouse1, Not a typewriter
12-10 11:51:57.555  1743  1982 D EventHub: No input device configuration file found for device 'Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouch System           '.
12-10 11:51:57.555  1743  1982 I EventHub: wakeMechanism=EPOLLWAKEUP, usingClockIoctl=true
12-10 11:51:57.555  1743  1982 I EventHub: New device: id=21, fd=264, path='/dev/input/event7', name='Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouch System           ', classes=0x80000014, configuration='', keyLayout='', keyCharacterMap='', builtinKeyboard=false, 
12-10 11:52:46.423  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouch System            due to epoll hang-up event.
12-10 11:52:46.423  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removed device: path=/dev/input/event7 name=Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouch System            id=21 fd=264 classes=0x80000014
12-10 11:52:46.427  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/mouse1' due to inotify event
12-10 11:52:46.430  1743  1982 I EventHub: Removing device '/dev/input/event7' due to inotify event`

From this log, I thought that the ELAN TouchScreen driver's idc file,elan-touchscreen.idc, was missing from the /system/usr/idc so I put that idc file too, but it didn't resolve my issue.

I also found out that the elan-touchscreen.idc is still there in Android Marshmallow but not in Nougat. Did Android stop supporting elan touch drivers?

So what I know is it's a touch driver issue.How can Solve it? Is it a way I can configure the ELAN Touch Screen driver in my Android Device? My Android device is running Oreo, Android 8.0.

Thanks in Advance